# Send exception from app_codevb in a web site asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, syntax-error, runtime-error

I've a question. In a web site created in asp.net with vb.net in code behind, how I can show message of exceptions from methods in app_codevb folder.

Example a method return a table with a list of customers, but occurs a error of timeout or error in sintax.

How I can show the user in the form the error occurred in app_codevb folder?

Comment: Pretty sure if you have debugging options enabled this is the default result of an unhandled exception...

Comment: I don't understand!. I've seen some throw exception but in windows forms. This apply in web forms???

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything then it will automatically show any unhandled errors on the page.

Somewhat in this format

> ### Server Error in '/WebApp' Application.
>
> ---
>
> Error Message...
>
> Description: ...
>
> Exception Details: ...
>
> Source Error: ...
>
> Source File: ...
>
> Stack Trace: ...
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: ...

However, it is not a good thing. It looks ugly and breaks your site. It also shows your immaturity in programming besides opening your site for attacks. The better way is to use `Try... Catch` blocks where there is a possibility of errors occurring in your application and handle the error appropriately.